# How is the .NETFramework,Version=X.AssemblyAttributes.cs file added into the build?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In a Windows C# project created using Visual Studio 2019 I see the file:

> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs

added to the solution with the following content:

```
// <autogenerated />
using System;
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.7.2")]
```

It's located under obj\Debug folder.

How does this C# file exist by itself?  It has no namespace specification and does not seem to be part of a class.  Is it pulled into the build by some sort of special convention?

NOTE: I know about the following question:

[Why does Visual Studio generates the following file .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs in the temp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200681/why-does-visual-studio-generates-the-following-file-netframework-version-v4-5-a)

The above question does not answer my question of how the file is pulled into the build.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kirillosenkov/msbuild-unnecessary-rebuilds-because-of-generated-assemblyattributes-cs

Comment: @stuartd Please see my edit, that question does not answer my question of how the file is pulled into the build.

Comment: That file is auto-generated by MSBuild.  Since it also generates the C# compile command, it has no trouble including that file.  Switch the build verbosity to Detailed to see it getting done, ought to give a hint why its location is wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you.  I am just trying to understand how the file stands on its own as .cs file, given that it has no namespace and class definitions.

Comment: Hmm, a namespace is useful for type declarations.  It doesn't have any, only the attribute matters.  The C# compiler does not know what .net version you target, so msbuild has to help.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you Hans.  If this question wasn't closed I could accept your answer.  If you'd like I can post new question and you can answer there.  Many thanks again, few people here like yourself.

Comment: This question was reopened.

Comment: @Sabuncu I have reopened the question as you requested. The duplicate was concerning why the file was created in the temp folder, however your file was created in the Debug folder, so I thought that technically it wasn't a duplicate. But if you're asking _"what is this file for and how does it work?"_ then that's still off-topic: only the MSBuild designers could answer that. I suspect the answer is - it's their build process and they can do it however they like.

Comment: @stuartd Thank you Stuart.  My question is this: **This is a .cs file but its content is unlike that of a typical C# file: it contains no namespace, no class definition.  It only contains using directives and a single attribute.  Does this not break rules as a standalone .cs file?  Apparently it does not, so what are the special exceptions that allow this sort of content.**  Thanks again.

Comment: @HansPassant This question has been reopened. I wonder if you'd consider posting your comment as an answer? Regards.